# Displaying QLabel with backslash

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a scenario where a path (setting in my program) is stored in a json file and I need to display it on a QLabel.

```
# self.progSettings is a dictionary containing the json content

labelStr = self.progSettings['testReportPath']

# labelStr now contains "C:\temp\testreports"
self.pathLabel = QLabel(labelStr) # No escape characters -> problem
```

I need to escape the backslashes in order to display the path correctly but I can't figure out how to do it easily and the "correct" way.

Thanks
Nicklas

Comment: I have difficulties imagining this. Can you provide us with a `print(repr(labelStr))` so we can see the actual content? Escaping should normally not be necessary.

Comment: That will print 
    "C:\temp\testReports"
However, the Qlabel text is displayed as: "C:[TAB] emp [TAB] estReports"

Comment: If you are setting your label via a string constant you will need to use a raw string ie, r"C:\temp\testreports"

Comment: Thanks @shao.lo ! Converting the string to a raw  string made the trick!
`labelStr = "%r"%self.progSettings['testReportPath']`